# Concerning US9559617B2 - METHOD AND DEVICE FOR GENERATING ELECTRICITY AND METHOD OF FABRICATION THEREOF Public view

Tags: thermodynamics

[This patent](https://patents.google.com/patent/US9559617B2/en?oq=US9559617B2) made some noise when first applied for, both as there was a thick sheaf of related patents applied for by Landa Labs at the same time, and as it seemed the patents were in violation of the 1st law of thermo. A lot of the siblings seem to have been abandoned but this one was granted and the owners are paying maintenance fees - anyone have any idea if this is anything more than a vanity project?

Comment: That application represents a tremendous amount of work! I noticed that the counterpart patent in Israel  IL211485A  is no longer in force due to nonpayment of renewal fees in 2020.

Comment: As worded your question is probably off topic here. You might ask about its path to get granted here or the actual  feasibility in Physics or maybe in Skeptics.

Comment: @GeorgeWhite Agreed that SE Physics is a better site for this.

Comment: Regarding paying maintenance fees. In most places it’s yearly but in the US it is 3.5 years then 7.5 years. So they have a couple more years before we can see if the US patent is worth $3,760 to them.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be much question about the physics (its pretty clearly not thermodynamically possible to generate electricity from thermal motion without recourse to a cold sink) - I was more interested in the context so I've reached out to some of those involved and was hoping someone here might conceivably shed light.

Comment: I should add that the currents they did manage to measure seem to be a 'battery effect' due to differences in the contact potential between the two sides of their device. If they left it running long enough it should run down, more or less borne out by Fig. 8